# REST API (http and https) Ajax Call is not working in Latest Cordova Ver 10.0.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cordova-android

I have developed an application by using **Cordova 9.0.0** and it's in production for more than years. Recently a few days back I upgraded my Cordova version from **9.x to 10.x**. After the upgrade, **Http and Https** (REST API) calls are not working in the **release build**.

Although the API calls are working fine in **android** **debug build**, tested on real android device (Realme 3 pro) and in chrome browser.

Since the issue has occurred in the **release build** I am unable to produce any error log.

I am using **AJAX** to make API calls.

**Note: All REST APIs are Https hosted.**

*AJAX Call*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://example.com/methodName",
    data: {
        data: mYData
    },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    timeout: 30000,
    success: function (data) {},
    error: function (message, textStatus) {}
```

Related Queries:

1. [Http and Https calls not working after Cordova upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329705/http-and-https-calls-not-working-after-cordova-upgrade)
2. [My release apk crash immediately but the debug app work properly ionic 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089197/my-release-apk-crash-immediately-but-the-debug-app-work-properly-ionic-5)

**EDIT:**
Below error response is log on API call.

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding ``alert(message)`` in your ``error: function()`` of your **AJAX** and then tried testing? If there is any error you can see that in the alert box on any device the app is installed.

Comment: @NotABot  Yes, It says [Object Object]

Comment: @NotABot Ok let me check and get back to you soon

Comment: Create a ``<div>`` for testing in your app then dump data from ``JSON.stringify()`` onto that ``<div>`` and then check for the errors.

Comment: @NotABot Hi I have just dumped the object in the testing Div and its says `{"readyState":0, "status":0, "statusText":"error"}`. This is the first time I am seeing such kind of error ;/

Comment: Can you update your question and post the image of the complete response you are getting, and do you getting any ``responseText``?

Comment: Also, this could be due to the ``cross-domain`` requests you are trying to make from the app to your server, and in Cordova 10.x these cross-domain requests might have been more difficult to make without proper authentication.

Comment: @NotABot updated my question, also I m not getting any `responseText` only three key-value pairs mentioned in the above screenshot.

Comment: Please check your ``Access-Control-Allow-Origin`` and also check for the **HTTPS** certificate. The server has **HTTPS** since you are sending a request using **HTTPS**  Since there are no issues in your code, thus only thing left is issue communication with the server

Comment: @NotABot thank you for guiding me through the issue. it helped me a lot :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the solution to my own question for developers facing the same problem and also for my future reference.

**Solution**

Add the attribute `android:usesCleartextTraffic` to `true` in **AndroidManifest.xml** file inside `<application>` tag.

**Reason**

When the attribute is set to `"false"`, platform components (for example, HTTP and FTP stacks, DownloadManager, and MediaPlayer) will refuse the app's requests to use cleartext traffic.

For More detailed Info visit
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic

Comment: What about iOS? it's not working for iOS also?

Answer (score 2):

There was a change between Cordova 10.0 and 10.1.
Please check your Cordova version and update to >10.1
The team added http support in 10.1. Please check release notes.
[Release Notes 10.1](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/08/16/cordova-android-10.1.0.html)

You have to add this element to the config.xml of your Cordova up.

```
<preference name="scheme" value="http" />
```

By default only https is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

For Android, I would suggest adding these lines in **config.xml**

```
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

[Source of solution](https://community.auth0.com/t/cors-issue-when-testing-on-android/80079/2)

Answer (score 0):

If not working even after setting android:usesCleartextTraffic=true. then remove whitelist plugin if already there. or remove other plugins. and reinstall plugin.  it will work. seems like plugins are not upgraded with higher version.